# Express / Node / Cloud9 - issues serving static files

Tags: node.js, express, static, cloud9-ide

I'm having an issue serving a simple static html file with Express on a Cloud9 server.

My file structure is simply:

```
/workspace
    /public
```

[Screenshot from c9.io here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvUI9.png)

And here's my code, I get a [Cannot GET/ (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E5Pi.png) when previewing in the browser.

static.js (located in the C9 workspace):

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

static.html (located in /public):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know the server's listening on the right port, because the preview works when I write directly to the response stream using Express, like this:

```
app.use(function(request, response) {
    response.end("Hello world!\n");
});
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

Apologies for the simplicity of the request, I just pared everything down to understand the fundamental reason I'm seeing "Cannot GET/".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cant see '/' route added to express. Have u added it actually in your code?  Something like app.get('/', function(req,res){})

Comment: From what I understand I don't need to add a route, it should just read what's in the public folder as I've written it with static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

renaming the file from static.html to index.html will work

Comment: So simple, flipping heck, I was going crazy over this. Thank you. Is there a way I could get the express.static method to read a file called anything other than index.html?